# SQL Lite Query (between in dates) doesn't work

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

in my small test program I have some SQL Queries. The first `SELECT * FROM kilometer;` works properly and returns all the columns in the table. So in Java embedded, `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM kilometer;");` returns an ResultSet which is not empty.

Now I wanted to get only the rows within a specific date. But my embedded query `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM kilometer WHERE datum BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31';");` returns an empty ResultSet. But I've tested it [online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/36b171/2/0) and it worked properly. Where is my mistake? I've consulted already some pages like [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/between.php), but I can't find the mistake.

I am using SQLite 3.15.1 and Java SE 8.

Full java code:

```
public ArrayList<Strecke> getErgebnisse(final String startzeitpunkt, final String zielzeitpunkt) {
ArrayList<Strecke> strecken = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    try {
        if (connection != null) {
        }
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + DB_PATH);
        if (!connection.isClosed())
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM kilometer WHERE datum BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31';");
    while (rs.next()) {
        strecken.add(new Strecke(Instant.ofEpochMilli(rs.getDate("datum").getTime()).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate(), rs.getString("startort"), rs.getString("zielort"), rs.getDouble("kilometer")));
    }
    rs.close();
    connection.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strecken;
}
```

Comment: why you used `try` inside `try`, and `if (connection != null)` section has no code?

Comment: Copy+Paste. I will do it more nice now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend that you use prepared statements while executing your queries instead of passing the query directly as a string......secondly I believe the problem here is that you are passing the date as a string in quotes and not a date.....I think that is the issue here. You would need to use sqllites datetime functions for this....

Comment: It wasn't me. But still `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM kilometer WHERE datum BETWEEN " + Date.valueOf("2016-01-01") + " AND " + Date.valueOf("2016-12-31") + ";");` is empty after changing to Date.

Comment: Not java date I was talking about using sqllite date functions for both datum and your date....alternatively another way is to store the timestamp and compare the timestamp

Comment: Hm, after consulting [this][0] page, it should even work with a date as a String. And actually I thought, everything I transmit with the JDBC Driver is a string and only converted within the database.


 [0]: https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/between.php

Comment: Now I was trying `ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM kilometer WHERE datum BETWEEN " + "date(2016-01-01)" + " AND " + "date(2016-12-31)" + ";");` but the ResultSet is still empty.